# AndEngine GLES2 TouchEven Exhaust error

Tags: java, android, andengine

Today i updated my project to GLES2 but i am having issues since the change..

Here is a issue i get when touching a sprite and dragging it across the screen.

```
01-01 21:13:00.336: V/AndEngine(2100):org.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 17 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
```

Parsed in 0.031 seconds, using GeSHi 1.0.8.4

I am basically just trying to allow the user to drag a sprite my clicking and holding it. This worked successfully in GLES1 but for some reason in GLES2 it doesnt. 
Anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: I have been investigating AndEngine's code for almost a hour now, but the code seems just fine. Try updaing your version.

Comment: By the way, it is *not* an error, but a **warning**. You can ignore it if you want to, but I don't recommend it. If you don't manage to solve it, you can switch back to GLES1, if there is nothing special you need in GLES2.

Comment: I may just do that. The only thing i wanted was the new BlackPawnTextureBuilder that allows padding to stop texture bleeding on SVG's. And Regulat textures

Comment: Well, this might be a bug; You can report it in AndEngine forums.

Comment: Yeah, I think i am just going to see if i can replace the old BlackPawnBuilder with the new one.